# send Messages to service without binding it

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

i have created one service by extending `Service` in android and i am sending `Message` to service using `Messenger` and `Handler`.

But the issue (which is a common behavior though) is whenever i have to send message to Service i have to `bind` it and when i go out of activity i have to `unbind` it which eventually destroys the service itself.

i can keep running service in background by fringing `startService` method but is there any way to send Messages to service without using `bind` as i don't want to destroy the service when i go out of activity.

Comment: sounds like a job for `IntentService`

Comment: Well IntentService finishes its work and ends itself but here i want to keep service running

Comment: but why do you want to keep the service running after _it finished it's work_? you could just call it again on demand...

Comment: are you stopping the service somewhere?

Comment: @waqaslam no m not stopping the service again

Comment: @DonL. because my service is fetching the user's current location in background

Comment: so your app doesn't stop the service at all?

Answer (score 6):

[LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) is a great way to  send messages/data,

In your service class create a private broadcastreciever and string for the intent action name:

```
public static String MSERVICEBROADCASTRECEIVERACTION ="whatevs";
private BroadcastReceiver mServiceBroadcastReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("foo","onReceive called");
        Log.d("foo","extra = " + intent.getStringExtra("foo")); // should print out " extra = bar"

    }
};
```

And register it in your `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
        // your other code...
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mServiceBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ServiceClassName.MSERVICEBROADCASTRECEIVERACTION));
    }
```

And De-register it in onDestroy()

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        // your other code...
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mServiceBroadcastReceiver);
    }
```

As for sending messages to it, from an activity or fragment:

```
    LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceClassName.MSERVICEBROADCASTRECEIVERACTION);
    // add some data 
    intent.putExtra("foo","bar");
    lbm.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

HTHs you send data without needing to `bind`!

Answer (score 0):

Unbind Service will not destroy the service. it will disconnect the service connection between the activity and service

Make sure you return START_STICKY to keep your service running

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
{
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Also make sure your running the service as  foreground 
using notification to keep running the service after the application is removed from stack.

```
startForeground(1000,mBuilder.build());  // mBuilder - notification builder
```

Comment: if its just disconnecting  then why my service's `onDestroy` is getting called at the time of unbinding service ?

Comment: make sure you are not stopping the service. use only unbindService(mConnection);

Comment: ok, i think your application(all activity) is removed from stack. see my updated answer